# Fastest way to share a flutter app with someone else

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a very simple flutter app which wants to share with a non-tec friend: What is the fastest way to do that. At this moment it's just UI. In the second scenario: If I integrate Firebase. What's the fastest way. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's Android, just build the apk and WhatsApp it to them. To build a release apk for most Android phones :

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64
```

If it's Apple, pay USD99 and follow the documentation. Then struggle. :-)

PS. Whether Firebase is integrated or not makes no difference in how you deploy the app to your users.

Comment: Thank you, Graham. It worked very well. Appreciate it. 

Comment: Glad it worked, knew it would, I do it all the time. Please mark the answer as the accepted one by clicking the tick :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution). It doesn't require any special set up on the testers side.

Comment: Thank you, Pavel. I absolutely will give it a try. Thank you for sharing this 

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively locked-down on the Apple side of things.  You must be a paid developer, and submit your app into the Test Flight program, and then you can send your friend a URL to install it from Apple.

I think it's a bit easier on the Android side... something about getting an .apk from somewhere.